# Disassociate file with cmd.exe

Tags: windows-7, java, command-line, file-association, jre

I recently chose cmd.exe as a default program for .jar files with instant regret.

How do I associate this back again with javaw.exe in the JRE? The default program check box is disabled, so selecting it again doesn't warrant a long term result.

I am using Windows 7. I'd appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get **[Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com)**

1. Start the program and click 'File Type settings'
2. Click 'Context Menu'
3. Select .jar from the list
4. On the context menu page, select 'Open' or whatever the default is. You can either delete it and add a new item called "open", or just click Edit
5. On the item page (either by adding or editing an item) browse to javaw.exe. It's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin` (or, if you're running 32bit, without the "(x86)" part.
6. Make sure the parameters look like this: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*`
7. Then save it, of course.

Like this:
[image: Default Programs Editor - Select 'open' for .jar files]

[image: Default Programs Editor - Set path to javaw.exe]

Comment: +1 This looks like a very nice prove of concept :-)

Comment: YES, fantastic! Thank you very much Factor Mystic, problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use `assoc` and `ftype` internal `cmd.exe` commands for that purpose

```
assoc .jar=jarfile
ftype jarfile="c:\program files (x86)\java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%*"
```

`assoc` associates an extension with a **file type**, and `ftype` sets the default program to open that file type with

Answer (score 0):

Instructions from following link (especially Method 1 & 2) might help:

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/06/20/how-to-edit-or-change-file-type-or-extension-associations-default-programs-in-windows-vista/

Comment: Again, this doesn't apply for Windows 7; but thanks anyway; I tried all of the methods on the pages, including some of the third-party software - no such luck.